# How to know Facebook app I'd through access token

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

today I am working on Facebook API and I want to know that is it anyway to know the app I'd and app name through access token...my one friend suggested that add this code but I don't know what this code actually do

```
$extend = get_html("https://graph.facebook.com/me/permissions?access_token="  . $token);
    if($exe == "41158896424" || $exe == "149859461799466"){
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the /app end point, which returns this type https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/application

```
$ oksocial https://graph.facebook.com/app
{
  "category": "Utilities",
  "link": "https://www.facebook.com/games/?app_id=550830111748623",
  "name": "OkSocial",
  "namespace": "oksocial",
  "id": "550830111748623"
}
```